# Vaadin 21: change date format at LocalDateTimeRenderer in Grid on locale change

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid, vaadin21

**Situation and problem, short**

The `LocalDateTimeRenderer` in Vaadin 21 shows a German date in a German browser, even if the Locale in the Vaadin session is changed to e.g. `Locale.UK`.

**Situation and problem, long / detailled**

In a Vaadin 21 `Grid` I've got a column for LocalDateTime. It's created like this for an entity type `T`:

```
private <T> Column<T> addLocalDateTimeColumn(Grid<T> grid, ValueProvider<T, LocalDateTime> getter) {
    LocalDateTimeRenderer<T> renderer = new LocalDateTimeRenderer(getter);
    Column<T> column = grid.addColumn(renderer).setAutoWidth(true);
    return column;
}
```

When I change the `Locale` in the session by calling `UI.getCurrent().getSession().setLocale(locale);` the whole application is translated into the new language, but not the content of the `LocalDateTime`-column.

Refreshing the whole `Grid` by calling `grid.getDataProvider().refreshAll()` (see here [Vaadin 21: re-translate column with ItemLabelGenerator on locale change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69993967/vaadin-21-re-translate-column-with-itemlabelgenerator-on-locale-change) ) causes the `ValueProvider` in the code example above to get called again (a good indicator I think) but it does not format the `LocalDateTime` in the new selected language (this is the unexpected behavior).

So even if the locale in the session is English / `Locale.UK`, the `LocalDateTime` value is formatted in German like this:
[image]

Using a localized DateTimeFormatter like this `LocalDateTimeRenderer<T> renderer = new LocalDateTimeRenderer(getter, DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.FULL, FormatStyle.SHORT));` also did not help: the style was different but the months were still translated German.

**Workaround**

Using a custom `TextRenderer` works (= column `LocalDateTime` content is translated with the session's locale):

```
private <T> Column<T> addLocalDateTimeColumn(Grid<T> grid, ValueProvider<T, LocalDateTime> getter) {
    Renderer<T> renderer = new TextRenderer<T>(new ItemLabelGenerator<T>() {

        @Override
        public String apply(T entity) {
            final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd. MMMM yyyy HH:mm", UI.getCurrent().getLocale());
            return getter.apply(entity).format(formatter);
        }
    });
    Column<T> column = grid.addColumn(renderer).setAutoWidth(true);
    return column;
}
```

**Question**

Is there some trick to get the same result with Vaadins `LocalDateTimeRenderer`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible to change the locale of a column dynamically if you're using `LocalDateRenderer` or `LocalDateTimeRenderer` in Vaadin 21 or Vaadin 22. This is because of the following:

1. The locale isn't explicitly saved in the Renderer. The Locale given to the renderer constructor (or the default) is used to produce a Formatter, which is saved into the field `private DateTimeFormatter formatter;`
2. The `formatter` doesn't have any getters or setters.
3. Even if the Locale of the `VaadinSession` changes, the `formatter`'s locale stays the same as what it was created with
4. You can't change the `Renderer` of a Column to something else after its creation.

What you *can* do is remove the Column and re-add it with a new `LocalDate(Time)Renderer` with the requested Locale.

I'd recommend creating a feature request about this in https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/